# JSON ругается на { }

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, json

```
{"0":"1","ID":"1","1":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","Date":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","2":"Student1","Name":"Student1","3":"student1@stud.com","Email":"student1@stud.com","4":"89123456789","Phone":"89123456789","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f","Comment":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}{"0":"2","ID":"2","1":"2017-10-21 20:20:49","Date":"2017-10-21 20:20:49","2":"\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439","Name":"\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439","3":"sad@dsfsd.com","Email":"sad@dsfsd.com","4":"89222222222","Phone":"89222222222","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"rrr","Comment":"rrr"}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

обрабатываю

```
 var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Разделите на два разных JSON:

```
var json1 = {"0":"1","ID":"1","1":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","Date":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","2":"Student1","Name":"Student1","3":"student1@stud.com","Email":"student1@stud.com","4":"89123456789","Phone":"89123456789","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f","Comment":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}
var json2 = {"0":"2","ID":"2","1":"2017-10-21 20:20:49","Date":"2017-10-21 20:20:49","2":"\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439","Name":"\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439","3":"sad@dsfsd.com","Email":"sad@dsfsd.com","4":"89222222222","Phone":"89222222222","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"rrr","Comment":"rrr"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пропущена запятая в

```
\u043d\u0438\u044f"}{"0":"2","ID":"2"
```

должно быть

```
\u043d\u0438\u044f"},{"0":"2","ID":"2"
```

и два объекта JSON должны быть помещены например в массив. Добавьте [ в начале и ] в конце.

Comment: а как мне поставить запятую?я эти данные с сервера получаю

Comment: Если сервер ваш, то править на сервере, чтобы он присылал валидный json. Если не ваш, то, например, data.replace("}{", "},{"). Конечно, если внутри данных не используется сочетание `}{`

Comment: а где на сервере то править?

Comment: по-видимому, там где данные переводятся в json перед отправкой.

Comment: Добавил, не помогает, ругается на запятую и  var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data)